# Bootstrap put responsive text and buttons on video

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

**Hey everyone so I'm having a slight problem. I am building a bootstrap site but I can't seem to put text and buttons on top of a video. Is there a way to do this so that the button and text are still responsive? This is what I have so far:**

```
<?php include('header.php');?>
<div class="container-fluid videoContainer">
    <div class="row">
                     <video preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="true">
                 <source src="StockTemplates/4thofJuly/4thofJuly_HD.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              </video>
          <h2 class="videoHeader">Prefessional-Quality Videos. Rendered Fast!</h2>
          <p class="videoParagaraph">Start with one of over 70 templates and create the perfect video to advertise your product or service</p>
          <a class="btn btn-primary videoButtonLeft" href="#" role="button">See Templates</a>
          <a class="btn btn-primary videoButtonRight" href="#" role="button">Make A Video</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Ideally I would like it to look something like this: [this is a mock up image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTgch.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**css**

```
  .overlay{position: absolute;
            display: flex;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-direction: column;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
           }
            .overlay .videoButtonWrapper{
                flex-direction: row;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }
            .videoBackgroundWrapper{position: relative; width: 100%;}
            .videoBackground{width: 100%;}
              .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
                  visibility: visible;
              }
```

**Here is the html I used use display flex. Look it up it works really really good guys. Thanks for all your help**

```
            <div class="videoBackgroundWrapper">
                     <video preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="true" class="videoBackground">
                 <source src="Balloon.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              </video>
                        <div class="overlay">
             <h2>Professional Quality Videos Rendered Fast!</h2>
             <p>Start with one of over 70 customizable templates amd create the perfect video to advertise your product or service.</p>
             <div class="videoButtonWrapper">
             <button class="btn btn-primary">See Templates</button>
             <button class="btn btn-primary">Make Video</button>
             </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put the video in an extra wrapper and put the content absolute over this wrapper.
If you want you can put the content in a container.

```
<div class="videoContainer">
  <video preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="true">
    <source src="StockTemplates/4thofJuly/4thofJuly_HD.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="position-absolute-wrapper" style="left: 15px; position: absolute; top: 50%; right:15px; transform: translate(0,-50%);">
      <h2 class="videoHeader">Prefessional-Quality Videos. Rendered Fast!</h2>
      <p class="videoParagaraph">Start with one of over 70 templates and create the perfect video to advertise your product or service</p>
      <a class="btn btn-primary videoButtonLeft" href="#" role="button">See Templates</a>
      <a class="btn btn-primary videoButtonRight" href="#" role="button">Make A Video</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```